# SQL Display DATE

Tags: sql, date

I have this query:

```
SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 AND MaxProduto = 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdCombustivel
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto <> 1 AND MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdLoja
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 and MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdMisto
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT PRENUMERO) AS Total FROM (
    SELECT  [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            ,MIN([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO])            AS MinProduto
            ,MAX([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO])            AS MaxProduto
    FROM    [VendasPOS_Linhas]
    INNER JOIN [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
       ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
    WHERE    UPPER([VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD]) IN ('T','F','C') 
      AND    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-11 00:00:00.000' 
      AND    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '404' 
    GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] , [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] )Res
```

And it gives this result:
[image]

I want to know if its possible to separate the rows with days. 
For example:

2015-06-10 x x x

2015-06-11 x x x

Comment: Yes, just include a Date field in the select

Comment: It gives me an error:

The multi-part identifier "VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.DATA" could not be bound.

Comment: See answer i posted with full query changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `Add>` lines for changes that you need to make.

```
SELECT 
Add>          [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] as Day, 
              COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 AND MaxProduto = 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdCombustivel
             ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto <> 1 AND MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdLoja
             ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 and MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdMisto
             ,COUNT(DISTINCT PRENUMERO) AS Total FROM (
        SELECT  [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] 
Add>            ,[VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA]
                ,MIN([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO])            AS MinProduto
                ,MAX([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO])            AS MaxProduto
        FROM    [VendasPOS_Linhas]
        INNER JOIN [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
           ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
        WHERE    UPPER([VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD]) IN ('T','F','C') 
          AND    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-11 00:00:00.000' 
          AND    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '404' 
        GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] , [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] )Res 
Add>    GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA]
```

Remove the `Add>` text before running, that is just there to show added lines.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this:  DATEPART(YYYY, Data) AS Ano,
   DATEPART(MM, Data) AS Mes,
   DATEPART(DD, Data) AS Dia, but just in one column?

Comment: Nevermind, I did it like this: CONVERT(varchar,Data,101) AS Data